# Can you effectively run lower power 5V TTL signals through a large piece of metal?

Tags: ttl, conductivity

Is it possible to run a standard TTL signal through a very large piece of metal?  For example, say 1-3 meters of metallic rebar?

Comment: What's the diameter of the rebar and what's the resistance, end to end? And will that rebar be buried inside a wet sponge (concrete/cement?) And will there be other metals in the wet sponge, as well? What metals will be in contact with it? Is this a suspended piece of rebar? (I'm leaning towards "no," I admit.)

Comment: Depends on many things, including the speed.  Generally this is not something that would be attempted or considered a good idea except as a party trick.  The related thing that might be would be some sort of *sensing scheme* but in that case the signal received would probably have explicit clamps and a more analog sort of input capability as what you might be sensing would be the *distortion* of the signal.

Comment: Dry rebar, say 1.25cm diameter (1/2").  No idea the resistance, not touching anything else - just a straight shot.  If anything was supporting it, the supports would be insulated.  It would be for part of a sculpture, where running additional wiring would not necessarily be possible.

Comment: If it isn't a high speed signal, it will work.

Comment: I guess I may have to setup some test cases...

Comment: What about the ground return? Are you also planning on using rebar as well, or some sort of common ground structure?

Answer (score 2):

Rebar conducts but is also inductive ~ 0.5uH/m so if you have any grid transients nearby, you should add RF caps. It will also pickup AM signals.

I suggest 100kHZ LPF.

ESD and EMI ingress needs to be suppressed , otherwise no problem.

Contact corrosion must be avoided.